# configuring build property for different environment

Tags: build, configuration, sitecore, staging, tds

I'm currently working on TDS and i'm trying to connect my TDS project to another dev environment which is 'Staging' but I was unable to connect due to restricted permission. 
It throws this error  ---->

```
 Connection Test Failed: Unable to download content from http://stg.website.com
Exception The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (WebException):
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ProjectTests.UrlTest.Execute()
Connection Test Finish: 2018-03-27 11:42:24
```

How can I connect my TDS project to staging for me to be able to sync sitecore items?

Comment: Is the TDS connector installed on the staging environment? Is the environment behind any IIS login?

Comment: How do I install TDS connector to the staging environment ? Yes it requires username and password.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll need to copy the _DEV folder from the existing dev sitecore instance to the new remote one. Also make sure to copy *HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll* to the bin.

Comment: Once I copied the _dev folder, they will be having same access guid. Is it okay to have the same Access Guid to different environment ? And what will be the next steps after I copied those files, how will I handle the IIS login ?

Comment: all you need is the _dev folder and the binary. The sync should work them. If you want to change the access guid, you can edit the web.conf under _dev

Comment: So once i copied those files , it will now be connected to my tds project ? Even though it has windows authentication that is asking for username and password ?

Comment: It will not work with Windows authentication in place. That's why you get the access error.

Comment: @pep you didnt mention windows auth in your post. Yes it wouldnt work then. You could build update packages and run them from sitecore manually.

Comment: Try allowing anonymous access just for the _Dev folder. It would be better to set up continuous delivery rather than deploying from a developers machine